# JAVA - split string with 2 delimiters

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I have a text file like this:

```
fname, lname~email~info
fname, lname~email~info
fname, lname~email~info
fname, lname~~info
```

I need to split these strings into either a 1 or 2D array. I have used this code:

```
  public void readFile() throws IOException {   
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("contacts.txt"));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        String everything = sb.toString();
        // store data into array
        for (String retval: everything.split("~")){
          System.out.println(retval);
        }

        // store data into array
        //String[] retval = everything.split("~");
        //System.out.println(retval[2]);


    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
  }
```

But the problem is the reader doesn't split the new lines, it ended up giving me this as a string

```
info
fname, lname
```

as a string (yes with the spaces)

How would I achieve this within one step of split? And note that the last line of text file doesn't have the email part, hence the the split should store an empty string, not skipping it.

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it to

```
 everything.split("~|[\r\n]+");
```

## EDIT:

```
for (String retval: everything.split("~")){
    if(retval !=null && !retail.isEmpty) {
       System.out.println(retval);
    } else {
       System.out.Println("String is empty or null");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this would split the space between fname and lname, I need "fname, lname" to be one string

Comment: What is the criteria to split?  Just the ~?  If so, then take out the `|\s+` part and you'll be good-to-go.

Comment: @Herious What your question again ? how do you want to split the string ? What do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to split these string using "~" and new lines

Comment: for new lines and ~ it should be everything.split("~|[\r\n]+");

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are looking to split on `~` and newline sequences. The following should work for you.

```
everything.split("~|[\r\n]+");
```